# Are function definitions present in header files?

Tags: c++, c, header, declaration, definition

In C/C++, are function definitions present in header files or only declarations?
Take for example function `pow()` in `math.h`. If function's definition is not present in the header file, then what does the header contain so that the function definition is properly linked?

Comment: Although I'm assuming that this question is referring to C/C++ header files, that is not explicitly stated. I'd recommend mentioning C or C++ in the question and adding their tag to it as well.

Comment: Why do you not open a headerfile and look what is inside?

Comment: Do you want to ask about C or C++?

Comment: It depends — with the C++ Boost library, many of them are implemented as 'header-only' code; they do not need a separate implementation.  Having `static inline` functions defined in a header can make sense in C.

Comment: Question 1, both can be present, for definitions the function must be specified as `inline`. Question 2, the header contains a function declaration aka function prototype. This ensures the function is properly linked (assuming everything else is correct as well). Sounds like a school question.

Comment: For some compilers, this doesn't happen automatically and you have to manually link in the appropriate library. For instance, on gcc you have to add -lm to link in the math library.

Comment: Reminder:  there is no requirement that a header file contain function definitions or declarations.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: *It depends.*

Long answer: *It depends.*

---

First: *What is a function definition?*

In C++, a function can be both *declared* as well as *defined*.

A declared function looks like this:

```cpp
// <cmath>

namespace std {
    double pow(double base, double exp);
}
```

While a defined one looks like this:

```cpp
#include <cmath>

double std::pow(double base, double exp) {
    // Do stuff...
}
```

The difference being that the defined function features a code block (denoted by the curly brackets `{...}`). So the difference between a declaration and a definition is that a definition features the underlying code of the function, whilst a declaration features no code whatsoever.

But assume that it's only declared, how does the compiler know where the function is located at?

Usually, C++ is compiled in different *translation units* (read: files). Each translation unit includes a common header file (here `<cmath>`), which provides the declarations of its functions (here `::std::pow`).

One of these units also contains the *definition* for `::std::pow`. When these units – either in the form of object files or libraries (a collection of units) – are placed together by the *linker*, all usage of the function will call the appropriate code located in the unit that defines it. If the unit that defines the function is not linked, the linker will complain with an error.

---

Do note that there can only be one definition. If multiple units had their own definition of `::std::pow`, the linker would again complain due to multiple definitions.

This *one definition rule* isn't universal, however, and the exceptions to it are:

1. *inline* functions (denoted by the `inline` storage class specifier specifier), which can be defined in multiple units but will end up with all but one definition discarded. This also includes [*constexpr*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr#constexpr_function) and [*consteval*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) (immediate) functions, both of which are implicitly inline.
2. *static* functions (denoted by the `static` storage class specifier), which are local to their translation unit; they do not conflict with symbols from other units – even if they share the same identifier.

---

But the case of `::std::pow` is actually rather complicated. Usually, it would have been defined externally. However, as of C++26, it is required to be a *constexpr* function, all of which are also inline *by definition* (see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow)).

The same goes for many of the other functions in the standard library. Many of them are defined externally (in another translation unit, such as [`::std::exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit)), but many are also defined in their respective header (such as [`::std::is_constant_evaluated`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated)). And in other cases, external functions are made inline in later standard editions (as is the case of `::std::pow`).

---

In conclusion, `::std::pow` might be defined in the `<cmath>` header... whilst it also might not be. It depends on the implementation and the edition of the standard.

But the general case is that, yes, functions are defined outside the headers that declare them (in another translation unit).

Comment: You may want to discuss the static function definitions or declarations.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Good idea! Will do.

Answer (score 1):

Header files are just source files which are included into your compilation unit by the preprocessor. Technically, they can contain any C or C++ code, but in practice, they are used to expose definitions/declarations between compilation units while hiding the implementation details.

In C, you cannot have two definitions for the same external object/function, so header files usually contain only function declarations or variable definitions.

In C++, a similar rule exists: the One Definition Rule. But there are few exceptions such a templates definitions, class member definitions, and function with the `inline` specifier. But their definitions have to match across all translation unit, otherwise the behavior is undefined.

In the case of `pow` the program has access to it because your compiler links the libc by default.